# Segmentation evaluation after border thinning not working

Tags: format, imagej

I am currently working on a image segmentation project with data from the ISBI-2012 segmentation challenge. I am trying to run the BeanShell script at this link: https://imagej.net/Segmentation_evaluation_after_border_thinning_-_Script

on my own predicted segmentation images. However, I cannot seem to reproduce the results with my images.

[predicted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTmPB.png)

[ground truth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxtmI.png)

and I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOqd.png) as a result. I understand that the generated cell labels must be in a certain format, as described on the ISBI-2012 site:

> The results are expected to be submitted as a 32-bit TIFF 3D image, which values between 0 (100% membrane certainty) and 1 (100% non-membrane certainty).

However, I have trouble understanding how exactly to save my images in this format. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need indeed to convert your image to 32-bit and make the values lie in the range [0.0 1.0].

You might do that in the script by simply adding two lines after line 59:

```
IJ.run( proposedLabels, "32-bit", "" );
IJ.run( proposedLabels, "Enhance Contrast...", "saturated=0.3 normalize process_all");
```

The ground truth image should be binary though.